# mmap returns can not allocate memory, even though there is enough

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, mmap, leveldb

I'm performing a pressure test with leveldb.

In `util/env_poisx.cc : NewRandomAccessFile()`

```
void* base = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

after 3 million  data (each 100k) insert. The errno says `Cannot allocate memory`.

why?

More details:

**top:**

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                         
19794 root      20   0  290g 4.9g 4.7g S 98.6  7.8   2348:00 ldb
```

**free -m:**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached

Mem:         64350      60623       3726          0        179      59353

-/+ buffers/cache:       1090      63259

Swap:          996          0        996
```

**ulimit -a:**

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1024
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 10240
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 530432
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

**sysctl:**

```
vm.max_map_count = 300000
kernel.shmmni = 8092
kernel.shmall = 4194304
kernel.shmmax = 2147483648
```

Answer (score 1):

man mmap:

"ENOMEM No memory is available, or the process's maximum number of mappings would have been exceeded."

When you write "3 million data (each 100k)", it seems to correlate with vm.max_map_count is 300000.
Try to change this limit if you sure you have enough memory.

Please give /proc/[pid]/maps | wc -l when error happening